# Passing parameter between 2 angular apps within a cordova app

Tags: angular, cordova

I have a cordova application which consists of 2 angular apps ("login-app" and "app"), with this structure :

```
index.html
login-app
  |-- ...
  |-- index.html    
app
  |-- ...
  |-- index.html
```

First, we get to "login-app" which redirects to "app" when the user credentials are right :

```
window.location.href = '../app/index.html';
```

Then, for some reason (update the user password for example), I want to go from "app" to "login-app", so I do something like this :

```
window.location.href = '../web-login/index.html?pageName=chgPwd';
```

In order to switch to the "login-app" and knowing that I want to change my password, so I can display the right component. 
In my browser console I get this :

```
Navigated to file:///android_asset/www/web-login/index.html?pageName=chgt-pwd
```

But I don't know how to get this "pageName" parameter in my angular component (in 'login-app'), I've tried this, with the variable 'route' of type 'ActivatedRoute' :

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
      console.log('pageName >>> ' + queryParams['pageName']);
});
```

But it is 'undefined'.

In fact, the URL is turned into this : 'file:///android_asset/www/web-login/#/' and I lose the parameter.

Is there a 'clean way' of doing this ? or maybe I have to set a parent global variable ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved by using localStorage